# Android UI update on fragments and Activities, using Aysnctask

Tags: android

I am facing a challenge on my UI in Android. The app am developing is getting sensor data from an Arduino.

The problem is when the app launches, the readings are displayed in real time as they change, but when navigate to another activity, and back to the activity which was displaying the results, they don't display anymore.

I am using `Asynctask`, for this communication. How can I recall or refresh the calling of this `new SensorData().execute("http://192.168.1.100")` so that the `onProgressUpdate()` can run again to update the UI?

Comment: Please post the whole code!

Answer (score 0):

You can try running your `AsyncTask` from `onResume()` method.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    new SensorData().execute("http://192.168.1.100");
}
```